# Is there some weakness to the simpler approach of calling Activity.method() from DialogFragment, rather than setting up a listener?

Tags: android, android-activity, uri, android-orientation, dialogfragment

After the user requests to delete a file (through a context menu), a DialogFragment is triggered to ask the user to confirm. If the user does confirm, the file is deleted by the calling Activity.

There are at least two ways for doing this.

1. The DialogFragment calls deleteFile(), a method in the Activity, itself accessible through getActivity().
2. The Activity implements a DeleteFile interface. The DialogFragment sets up a Uri, initializes the listener to be the Activity, and sends a message to the listener. For additional safety, onAttach() confirms that the Activity does implement the requisite interface.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) suggests that the second option is superior, at least generally. But in this case the first approach seems perfectly robust no matter when the user has triggered a rotation (which resets both the Activity and the DialogFragment).

Is the first approach perfectly adequate, or is there a scenario other than rotation that makes the second approach better.

Comment: I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with your non-listener approach. There are many solutions to each problem, use whichever technique works best for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both implementations can accomplish what you're trying to do, but there are certainly some differences between the two. In most cases, interfaces are not completely "necessary", you can always cast to a concrete class and call a method. The benefit interfaces provide is in decoupling. If you use an interface, the `DialogFragment` is not tied to a specific `Activity`. Any `Activity` could implement the same interface and be used with the `DialogFragment`, making that `Fragment` more reusable (which is half of the point of fragments).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that both implementations are equivalent, given that both of them require the activity to adhere to a specific contract (the class in the first case, the interface in the second). You can't avoid to cast the activity to the specific interface / class.

Another approach you could try is to have (most) of the logic implemented in the fragment itself. I don't know if it suits your case but it would certainly help you in reusing the fragment. Maybe it's less suitable for dialogfragments..

Comment: Actually in the first approach a cast is not even necessary, just so long as the method returns a boolean. Implementing the logic in the fragment is possible, but there is no avoiding sending a message to the Activity to tell it to refresh its view (in effect simulating a trigger to onResume).

Comment: When you call getActivity() you have to cast to the activity of your type (which have deleteFile() method)

Comment: Sheesh.. I take it back. There was no mysterious casting happening. deleteFile() just happens to be defined for Activity. I wish @Override wasn't optional. In any case, back to the question. It is still considerably briefer/simpler to call a method after a cast rather than set up a listener. Why does the documentation suggest the latter?